# How to change Port 27000 from filtered to open status

Tags: networking, firewall

In my ubuntu box I am running flexlm licensing software on port 27000 and I am able to pull the license from the this port to run the simulation software locally.

I am also trying to run the same software in another Linux machine (opensuse) by using the flexlm license from the Ubuntu box. However, my opensuse box is unable to communicate with port 27000 in my Ubuntu box.

I have turned off the firewall on the Ubuntu box, played around with iptables and when I do a `nmap` from my opensuse box to Ubuntu box the message I get is that port 27000 is on filtered status. My understanding is that filtered status does not allow the opensuse box to communicate with Ubuntu.

My question is how to change port 27000 from filtered status to open status? Hope someone can help me out. Thank you.

Andy here is the iptables and I am using UFW

```
cranjan@ubuntu:~$ sudo iptables -L
[sudo] password for cranjan: 
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
fail2ban-ssh  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports ssh 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_home    all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `'IN-unknown:'' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `'PASS-unknown:'' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
out_home   all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
out_windows  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `'OUT-unknown:'' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain fail2ban-ssh (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain in_home (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
in_home_all_c1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_home_irc_c2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_home_ftp_c3  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_home_ssh_s4  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_home_ping_s5  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_home_samba_s6  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_home_samba_c7  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `''IN-home':'' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain in_home_all_c1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state ESTABLISHED 

Chain in_home_ftp_c3 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ftp dpts:32768:61000 state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ftp-data dpts:32768:61000 state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpts:32768:61000 state ESTABLISHED 

Chain in_home_irc_c2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:ircd dpts:32768:61000 state ESTABLISHED 

Chain in_home_ping_s5 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW,ESTABLISHED icmp echo-request 

Chain in_home_samba_c7 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:netbios-ns dpt:netbios-ns state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:netbios-ns dpts:32768:61000 state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:netbios-dgm dpt:netbios-dgm state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:netbios-dgm dpts:32768:61000 state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:netbios-ssn dpts:32768:61000 state ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:microsoft-ds dpts:32768:61000 state ESTABLISHED 

Chain in_home_samba_s6 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:netbios-ns dpt:netbios-ns state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spts:1024:65535 dpt:netbios-ns state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:netbios-dgm dpt:netbios-dgm state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spts:1024:65535 dpt:netbios-dgm state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:netbios-ssn state NEW,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:microsoft-ds state NEW,ESTABLISHED 

Chain in_home_ssh_s4 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpt:ssh state NEW,ESTABLISHED 

Chain in_windows (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
in_windows_smtp_s1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows_http_s2  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows_ftp_s3  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows_dns_s4  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows_squid_s5  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows_dhcp_s6  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows_http_s7  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows_icmp_s8  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
in_windows_icmp_c9  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 1/sec burst 5 LOG level warning prefix `''IN-windows':'' 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain in_windows_dhcp_s6 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere            udp spt:bootpc dpt:bootps 

Chain in_windows_dns_s4 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp spt:3128 dpts:1024:65535 state ESTABLISHED                                                                                                                      netstat-anigrep                                                          cranjan@ubuntu:~$ netstat -an|grep LIST
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:445             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:139             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49493           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:27000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10192    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-849-0-5cf869d15b3ec
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8754     @/tmp/dbus-OEZITogft8
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10203    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-848-0-32221e795bc88
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10635    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-855-0-43c3de6d81f95
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10657    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-853-0-217a10f785bd6
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10663    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-859-0-e63817d85cf2
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10752    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-860-0-275125c19a706
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10760    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-857-0-1b7175879ac02
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10779    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-85a-0-4dd32e9c9daed
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10901    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-864-0-66e40c5eb66ae
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11414    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-86c-0-5afc43ec99b12
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11652    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-86f-0-6909ae8e71c13
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     28839    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-8ce-0-67cf32c7a4000
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     146671   /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-940-0-1cca5987ea42
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4645     /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7005     @/var/run/hald/dbus-9rWZEhUxZV
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2665     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4157     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4883     @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5741     /var/run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7036     /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8741     /tmp/ssh-Awxvql2002/agent.2002
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5281     @/tmp/gdm-greeter-EhaaTCYd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8782     @/tmp/.ICE-unix/2002
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4283     /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8783     /tmp/.ICE-unix/2002
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4884     /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8803     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-7fb-0-394d0c2c7bba5
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9022     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-7d2-0-749e269d7e12a
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9152     /tmp/keyring-27bLif/ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20196    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-89e-0-7a28b4d49ee3d
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20261    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-8a4-0-5c25fd95ab7d8
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     20349    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-8a8-0-7a28b4d4b67cd
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5458     @/tmp/gdm-session-VYGLKeYD
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8495     /tmp/keyring-27bLif/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9154     /tmp/keyring-27bLif/pkcs11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9171     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-802-0-6eb9d50bd0fdc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9957     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-816-0-2ed05eef44122
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9664     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-811-0-7c48fbd4f30bc
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9666     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-80f-0-655b9438f3104
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9668     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-815-0-3100350bf3161
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9682     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-814-0-399a7b5bf360b
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9688     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-818-0-14a559eef3944
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9829     /tmp/.esd-1000/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9832     /home/cranjan/.pulse/77caea2cdb600d3427a2a8684c86c409-runtime/native
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9928     /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-834-0-4a80ef294001d
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7000     @/var/run/hald/dbus-xHxwQeLK6K
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10073    /tmp/orbit-cranjan/linc-83c-0-4d7ce2a153a11
cranjan@ubuntu:~$                                                Thanks for your help.
```

Comment: What firewall software are you using?

Comment: It could be helpful to post the output of `iptables -L` and `netstat -an|grep LIST`

Comment: Andy here is the iptables -L